# How to share data between routes in express?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, backend, mern

```
        router.post('/',[
        check('name', 'Name is required').not().isEmpty(),
        check('username', 'Username is required').not().isEmpty()
        check('email', 'Please include a valid email').isEmail(),
        check('password', 'Please enter a password with 8 or more characters').isLength({min:8})
    ], async (req, res) => {
           user = new User({
                  name,
                  username,
                  email,
                  password,
    });
}

    router.get('/send', async function (req, res) {
      res.send(email); //Here I need to access email right after router.post
    });
```

As you see user register and I code will send email verification. But I need to access email which just input in 'api/'. I need this email in 'api/send' and 'api/verify' as well. In a word I don't know how to pass data from one route to another one.

Answer (score 1):

Combine these actions into a single route, or use inside a send rout get data from the databases model where you saved the user. For example(pseudocode):

```
// First option: combine
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    user = new User({
          name,
          username,
          email,
          password,
    });

    const savedUser = MyDatabase.save(user);

    MyEmailSander(email);

    res.send(email);
};

// Second option: work with DB
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    user = new User({
          name,
          username,
          email,
          password,
    });

    const savedUser = MyDatabase.save(user);

    res.send(email);
}

router.get('/send', async function (req, res) {
  const user = MyDatabase.find(req.body.user.id);

  MyEmailSander(user.email);

  res.send(email);
});
```